# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 1)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am using keras MLP network for binary classification of 3-D word vector `input_shape=(None,24,73)`. I have used two dense layers `dense_1` and `dense_2`. At `dense_2` I'm getting an error which I've not been able to solve.

This is my model summary.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 8, 90)             6660      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 8, 1)              91        
=================================================================
Total params: 6,751
Trainable params: 6,751
Non-trainable params: 0
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (22, 1)

Comment: show us the data shape of your target (y). From what I can see here the error is complaining that your target and the output of the model dont have the same shape

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a binary_classification task your last layer should look something like this

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Right now you model is out puting 3D array which don't match the shape of
your target (2D)